# getFragmentByTag() return Fragment, but getFragmentByTag().getView() return null

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have 3 Fragments, that I'd love to add them programatically,

The "mainQuiz.java"

```
package mobi.hkgh.tracnghiem_package;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;


public class mainQuiz extends FragmentActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_quiz);

    if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("head")==null) {
        head_status_fragment head = new head_status_fragment();
        main_content_fragment main_content = new main_content_fragment();
        choice_fragment choice = new choice_fragment();


        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        ft.add(R.id.main_quiz_layout, head, "head");
        ft.add(R.id.main_quiz_layout, main_content, "main_content");
        ft.add(R.id.main_quiz_layout, choice, "choice");


        ft.commit();
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
    }
    quiz();
}

public void quiz() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    main_content_fragment kk = (main_content_fragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("main_content");
    View z = kk.getView();

    if(z==null) {
        ft.remove(fm.findFragmentByTag("choice"));
    }
    ft.commit();
    fm.executePendingTransactions();
}
```

}

The "head_status_fragment.java":

```
package mobi.hkgh.tracnghiem_package;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class head_status_fragment extends Fragment  {
public void head_status_fragment(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.head_status_fragment, parent, false);
        return view;
}


}
```

the "main_content_fragment.java":

```
package mobi.hkgh.tracnghiem_package;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class main_content_fragment extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_content_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
}
```

}

and, the "choice_fragment.java":

```
package mobi.hkgh.tracnghiem_package;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

public class choice_fragment extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choice_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}
}
```

as you can see, the 'z' variable get null, I could not figure out why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could not figure out why?

`onCreateView()` has not been called on the fragment yet.

IMHO, an activity should **not** be trying to mess with the widgets of its fragments. Delegate that work to the fragment, which can do that work at an appropriate time, when the widgets are ready.

Comment: I don't understand "onCreateView() has not been called on the fragment yet.", Could you be more clear about this?

Comment: @BùiVănThủ: `getView()` will return `null` until your fragment's `onCreateView()` has been called to establish what the fragment's `View` actually is.

Comment: So, how could I check whether onCreateView() has been called or not?

Comment: @BùiVănThủ: Ideally, you don't. As I wrote in my answer, you stop having the activity mess with the widgets of its fragments. The fragment *itself* can update *its own widgets* in *its own implementation of `onCreateView()`* (or any later point, as you see fit).

Comment: I want to change a TextView() in the Fragment, so, I think findViewById() is the most flexible way.

Comment: I meant, to change TextView() in Fragment from Activity.

Comment: @BùiVănThủ: That is the *least* flexible way, as now the activity has to be aware of the internal implementation of the fragment, in addition to the activity now having to know the internal *lifecycle* of the fragment to know when that widget exists. Pass the data to the fragment, which can hold onto it an apply it to the widget when the widget is created, if it does not already exist.